# Difference in pixel quantity calculation using Google Earth Engine-GEE, QGIS and R

Tags: qgis, r, google-earth-engine, reduceregion

I would like to perform the pixel count of certain classes. I have a raster with interior values with classes from 1 to 33. I also have a shapefile with 4 features.

Using the `terra` package I did the accounting of these pixels according to the class and the 4 features of the shapefile. In QGIS I also did this using the `zonal statistics` function. The results for R and QGIS are identical.

When performing this command in Google Earth Engine using the function `ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram()` I got values one different from those obtained by QGIS and R. GEE returns me decimal values, while QGIS and R return integer values.

In the GEE documentation, the information is too superficial about the operating structure of the `ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram()` command to understand how it does this statistic. I also saw that there is the command `ee.Reducer.histogram()` but I didn't understand the difference to the other.

Why this difference? is there something I can control in `ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram()` to get closer to the QGIOS and R result?

follows my code in GEE and prints of R and QGIS.

GEE link https://code.earthengine.google.com/325093568bf4e183ac3b0df96de277f6

code

```
//shp ROI
var roi = table

//impor image
var land_use = image.select('b1')
  
var stats = land_use.reduceRegions({
    collection: roi,
    reducer:ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
    scale: 30,
    })

//Stats
var stats_mapa = stats
Map.addLayer(stats_mapa, {}, 'stats_mapa')
print(stats)

//Select data for export
var land_use_count=stats.select(['nome_id','histogram']);

//add layers
Map.addLayer(land_use, {
  band:['b1'],
  min:1,
  max:41,
  palette: ['ffa500', 'ff0000', '818181', '06ff00', '4169e1', '8a2be2'],
})

Map.addLayer(roi, {}, 'vector')
Map.centerObject(roi3, 12.5)

//Export Result in CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: land_use_count,
description: 'testes',
folder: 'GEE_regina',
fileNamePrefix: 'regina_teste_uso_solo_freq',
fileFormat: 'CSV',
selectors: ['nome_id', 'histogram']
});
```

Comparison for region 1 from GEE, R and QGIS results

R result package `terra`

[image]

QGIS `Zonal Statistics`

[image]

GEE `ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram()`

[image]

Note that the class 15 difference is very big between GEE and R/QGIS

Comment: At a guess based on GEE returning fractional values, are QGIS and R only counting whole pixels (either all pixels fully or partially inside the polygon) and GEE is counting pixel area, with pixels on the edge counting as fractions of one?

Comment: @Spacedman I would like to understand this, because the GEE documentation does not explain how to count pixels with ee.Reducer(). But R/QGIS do inner pixel counting.

Comment: The `exactextractr` package in R can do fractional pixel-polygon statistics (and really fast too) so if you want to try that... I'm no GEE expert though and the docs are a bit skinny...

Answer (score 0):

The Earth Engine documentation explains how pixels are counted with an `ee.Reducer` [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_region#pixels-in-the-region).  So you might want to fiddle with the weighting, depending on how the other software does it.  You may also want to check the `maxRaw` parameter of [`ee.Reducer.histogram`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-histogram), which should be as large as your inputs.